# How to convert 3 variable quadratic form into a sum of squares?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, economics, sums-of-squares, completing-the-square

How do I convert the 3-variable quadratic form q(x₁ x₂ x₃) = row vector [x₁ x₂ x₃] multiplied by [a₁₁ a₁₂ a₁₃ a₂₁ a₂₂ a₂₃ a₃₁ a₃₂ a₃₃]₃ₓ₃ matrix multiplied by column vector [x₁ x₂ x₃] into the equation:
$$
|A_1|\left(x_1 + x_2 a_{12}/a_{11} + x_3 a_{13}/a_{11}\right)^2 + (|A₂|/|A₁|)\left(x₂ + x₃(a₁₁a₂₃ - a₁₂a₁₃)/(a₁₁a₁₂ - a²₁₂)\right))^2 + (|A₃|/|A₂|)x^2_3  
$$
by "completing the square" method? Please be as detailed as possible, it's doing my head in... thank you.

$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}& a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21}& a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31}& a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Please typeset the question in an intelligible way.

Comment: By the way, what are $|A_1|, |A_2| $ ?

Comment: @MattiP. Hey thank you so much for editing my question, I'm really new to this thing. |A₁| is a₁₁ and |A₂| is the determinant of [a₁₁  a₂₁ a ₁₂ a₂₂]

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you so much for the hint, I really appreciate it. I've just joined the website and I'm gonna get the hang of inputting everything properly with time

Comment: I discuss an algorithm for symmetric matrices at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr    Eventually I saw Lagrange's method in Gantmacher's book, Lagrange had a very specific step when all remaining diagonal entries were zero...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ax^2+2bxy+2cxz+\cdots=a\left(x+\frac bay+\frac caz\right)^2-\frac{b^2}ay^2-\frac{c^2}az^2+\cdots$$